# Django models: Choose a FK from two options (Just one)

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, backend

This is the models.py from a Subscription app. Some fields have been omitted, to simplify the code.

```
# PLAN
class Plan(BaseVersionPlusModel):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=17, 
                            primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service, 
                                      through='subscriptions.PlanService', 
                                      blank=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, 
                                      through='subscriptions.PlanProduct', 
                                      blank=True)

class PlanService(BaseVersionPlusModel):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, 
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan,
                             related_name='plan_services', 
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    limit = models.FloatField(default=9999)

class PlanProduct(BaseVersionPlusModel):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, 
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan,
                             related_name='plan_products', 
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    limit = models.FloatField(default=9999)

# SUBSCRIPTION
class Subscription(BaseVersionPlusModel):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,
                                on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
                                blank=True)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan,
                             on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
                             blank=True, 
                             null=True)
# CONSUME
class ServiceConsume(BaseVersionPlusModel):
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, 
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ProductConsume(BaseVersionPlusModel):
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, 
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to get the Consume model in just one table instead of ServiceConsume and ProductConsume. Someting like this:

```
Class Consume(BaseVersionPlusModel):
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    **service/product = FK(Service/Product) #But choosing only one**
```

Is this possible in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
Class Consume(BaseVersionPlusModel):
   subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   service = models.ForeignKey(Service, 
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, 
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
```

Here you can either choose service or product. Product and service are optional to use. In case, you use service, then you can ignore product in a sense and vice versa. I think that will help you out.